# How to groupeby and paste string in python

Tags: python, string, pandas, group-by, multiple-columns

My data looks like this.

```
ID              Position            Treatment
--20AxECvv-         0           A
--20AxECvv-         -1          C
--20AxECvv-         -2          B
--h9INKewQf-        0           A
--h9INKewQf-        -1          B
zZU7a@8jN           0           C
QUeSNEXmdB          0           C
QUeSNEXmdB          -1          A
qu72Ql@h79          0           C
```

**Question 1:**

I want to have all the treatment took by one user (id) according to its position and separated by a '-'.

The result would be :

```
ID                       Treatment

--20AxECvv-              B-C-A
--h9INKewQf-             B-A
zZU7a@8jN                C
QUeSNEXmdB               A-C
qu72Ql@h79               C
```

**Question 2**

And after knowing all the treatment path, I want to count how many times tratment C (placebo) is with A and B.

```
Outcome : 
treatment (placebo)          other treatment           times
C                            A                         2
C                            B                         1
```

And how many time people take it in last (when patient has taken others)

```
Outcome : 
treatment placebo in last          other treatment           times
C                            A                                1
C                            B                                0
```

Thanks in advance to take some time to these questions :)

Comment: Are you using Pandas? It's not a tag so it's unclear.

Comment: Yes, sorry I will edit the tag

Answer (score 2):

You want groupby and sum I think

```
>>> y = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["x", "treatment"], data=[[0,"a"],[1,"b"],[0,"c"]])
>>> y
   x treatment
0  0         a
1  1         b
2  0         c

>>> y.groupby("x").sum()
  treatment
x          
0        ac
1         b
```

Sum will concat strings since "a" + "b" = "ab" in python

If you need the treatments separated by a string try

```
>>> y.groupby("x")["treatment"].apply("-".join)
x
0    a-c
1      b
```

Comment: But it was a simplified data, there is a lot of different treatment ....

Comment: Ok I've edited my answer to include a way to keep the treatments separated by a string. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I have this as error : TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: You can try to cast the column to a string using `astype(str)`, but I think you should probably check through your data. Are the treatment labels meant to be floating point numbers? I assume not. You could be selecting the wrong column.

Comment: The treatment label are a mix between letters, numbers and specific characters as " / " or " - "

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your **Question 1**:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('yourfile', header=None, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=1)
df.columns = ['ID','Position','Treatment']
grouped = df.sort_values('Position').groupby('ID')
grouped = grouped.agg(lambda x: '-'.join(x)).reset_index()

print(grouped)
```

The output:

```
             ID Treatment
0   --20AxECvv-     B-C-A
1  --h9INKewQf-       B-A
2    QUeSNEXmdB       A-C
3    qu72Ql@h79         C
4     zZU7a@8jN         C
```

Comment: Hello, when I do this, the result for each rows is thant the column position and tratment contain : "id - posiiton - treatment"

Comment: @AnnaCarrere, what do you mean? I have copy-pasted your input into file, applied my approach and it gave the expected result

Comment: I do excatly what you write except the first row (df = pd.read_table('yourfile', header=None, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=1) because I already have my table from previous code executions.

Comment: you mean, your input data does not contain row `ID              Position            Treatment` ?

Comment: No, it contains. but the output contain only rows with id-treatment-position